# Run time error '13': Type mismatch when trying to fill text box

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

Whilst trying to populate two seperate fields, i'm receiving a runtime 13 error

the code to add the text to the fields is

`Private Sub cmdAddMDS_Click()
   SetText GetMDS(currentMDS, cboxMDS.Value) 
    SetCat catMDS(currentMDS, cboxMDS.Value) <-- This creates the runtime error
End Sub`

The Subs to set the value to be added are near identical, just different sub name and offset

```
Function GetMDS(mdsName As Worksheet, templateName As String) As String

Dim Lrow As Long, rng As Range

On Error Resume Next

Lrow = mdsName.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

With mdsName.Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

    Set rng = .Find(templateName, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        GetMDS = rng.Offset(, 1).Value
    End If

End With

End Function

----------------------------------------------------------
Function catMDS(mdsName As Worksheet, templateName As String) As String

Dim Lrow As Long, rng As Range

On Error Resume Next

Lrow = mdsName.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

With mdsName.Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

    Set rng = .Find(templateName, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        catMDS = rng.Offset(, 3).Value
    End If

End With

End Function
```

Does anyone have any Insight to what may be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
SetCat catMDS(currentMDS, cboxMDS.Value)
```

two things can trigger a type mismatch error:

> 1) There is a problem passing the parameters to the function `catMDS`
>
> 2) There is a problem passing the returned string to `SetCat`

Since the values passed to `catMDS` *appear* to be the same as the values passed to `GetMDS` and those two functions have the same type, explanation 1) is unlikely. BUT -- all bets are off if `SetText` modified one of those values.

Thus -- 2) is likely to be the case. Since you haven't revealed what `SetCat` does, we have no way of knowing why it would cause an error. You might want to edit your question to include that sub.

For debugging purposes, you could modify your code as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdAddMDS_Click()
   Dim s As String
   SetText GetMDS(currentMDS, cboxMDS.Value)
   s =  catMDS(currentMDS, cboxMDS.Value)
   SetCat s 
End Sub
```

This will separate the function call from the sub call. One of the last two lines should throw an error. Which line throws the error will allow you to focus your debugging efforts.

Comment: When debugging as mentioned the error appeared on    `s= catMDS(currentMDS, cboxMDS.Value)`    the code for setCat is to amend the contents of a cell into a text box as below    `Sub SetCat(ByVal txt As String, Optional append As Boolean = False)

    txt = txt & vbNewLine & "_______________________________________" & vbNewLine

    If append = True Then
        frmMDS.catMDS.Text = (frmMDS.catMDS.Text + vbNewLine) & txt
    Else
        frmMDS.catMDS.Text = txt
    End If
    
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the answer, i was using the same name for two different parameters which was causing a conflict

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. By the way -- `On Error Resume Next` is seldom a good idea. All too often it becomes `On Bug Hide Error`. It is better to use explicit error handling rather than doing the VBA equivalent of removing the batteries from your smoke detector.